# Multiple Value Variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to assign multiple values to a variable?
I am coding a solitaire game and using the values of ACE through KING for the cards. Is there any way to assign a variable the value of "ACE" and the value of "1" and so on, KING being "13"? This is not necessary, but would make the code a lot simpler and easier to create.

---

Thank you all, I currently have this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Card = namedtuple('Card', 'name value')
ace = Card(name="ACE", value=1)
```

When I do:  `print(ace)` I end up with:`Card(name="ACE", value=1)` and when I do ace.name or ace.value, I get the right outcome as well.

Is there any way to have the "ace" value in a list, and withdraw just the name?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `dictionary` data type: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Answer (score 4):

You could use a class or [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) to wrap both pieces of data

```
from collections import namedtuple

Card = namedtuple('Card', 'name value')
ace = Card(name="ACE", value=1)
king = Card(name="King", value=13)
```

A custom class might be better because then you can implement logic like `card1 < card2`

> could I make the statement stackA + 1 == stackB true?

Yes, if you implement an `__radd__` and `__eq__` methods on the Card type that accept adding other Cards to int types and comparing the results to other Card types

Comment: cricket_007 if i did this would i be able to use the value "ACE" and the value "1" seperately?

Comment: Yes. `ace.name` or `ace[0]`, as mentioned in the link to the docs will produce `"ACE"`

Comment: how would i recall the value idea from the namedtuple?

Comment: Same way, different field/index.

Comment: If i had a list: listA = [ace, "fake", "fake"] ... When I do "print(listA[0])", I get "Card(name="ACE", value=1)"...   Is there anyway to just recall the name or just the value?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned already, *and in the documentation* link... `print(listA[0].name, listA[0].value)`

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary.

```
{'ace' :1, 'two' :2', ...etc}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class:

```
class Card(object):
    # fancier output
    s = {0:"hearts", 1:"diamonds", 2:"clubs", 3:"spades"}
    r = {i:v for i,v in enumerate( [ "Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",
                                     "9","10","Jack","Queen","King"],1)}
    def __init__(self, suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(Card.r[self.rank],Card.s[self.suit])

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return (self.suit,self.rank) < (other.suit, other.rank)


    @classmethod
    def summ_hand(cls,hand):
        return sum ( 10 if card.rank > 10 else card.rank for card in hand)


class Deck(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit,rank) for suit in range(4) for rank in range(1,14)]


deck = Deck()

print( deck.cards )
```

Output:

```
[Ace of hearts, 2 of hearts, 3 of hearts, 4 of hearts, 5 of hearts, 6 of hearts, 
 7 of hearts, 8 of hearts, 9 of hearts, 10 of hearts, Jack of hearts, Queen of hearts, 
 King of hearts, 
 Ace of diamonds, 2 of diamonds, 3 of diamonds,4 of diamonds,5 of diamonds, 6 of diamonds, 
 7 of diamonds, 8 of diamonds, 9 of diamonds, 10 of diamonds, Jack of diamonds, 
 Queen of diamonds, King of diamonds, 
 Ace of clubs, 2 of clubs, 3 of clubs, 4 of clubs, 5 of clubs, 6 of clubs, 7 of clubs, 
 8 of clubs, 9 of clubs, 10 of clubs, Jack of clubs, Queen of clubs, King of clubs, 
 Ace of spades, 2 of spades, 3 of spades, 4 of spades, 5 of spades, 6 of spades, 
 7 of spades, 8 of spades, 9 of spades, 10 of spades, Jack of spades, Queen of spades, 
 King of spades]
```

Providing `__lq__(self)` allows you to sort:

```
hand = random.choices(deck.cards, k=7)
print(hand)
print(sorted(hand))

print( Card.summ_hand([Card(0,9),Card(0,11),Card(0,13)]))
```

Output:

```
# as given by choices
[Ace of hearts, Ace of spades, Queen of diamonds, 9 of spades, 
 King of hearts, Ace of spades, 3 of diamonds]

 # sorted
[Ace of hearts, King of hearts, 3 of diamonds, Queen of diamonds,
 Ace of spades, Ace of spades, 9 of spades]

29  # summ_hand for 9,Queen,King,
```